# Could not create epoll instance. errno=24

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

what does this runtime-error mean?

I already googled it, some say, it belongs to timers, other say its a socket error and more say, it belongs to pictures. I have sockets and timers (lot of timers) and i have no idea, which of these causes it. SOmetimes it works for over an hour, and other times just for 5 minutes. Any Ideas?

A basic impression of what this error is about is enough. If i would post all the code, where it could happen, this page  would be multiple kilometres long ( a little extreme of course, but it is lot of code.)

Found right now, it could belong to `too many open files` but im not using any extern files in my app.

Seems to be a memory leak, belonging to this part:

```
public static Runnable connection() throws IOException {
    Log.e("Communication", "connection");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            try {
                serv = new ServerSocket(port);                                                                      sock = serv.accept();
                reader();                                                                               } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
    return null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deleting a part of the code above everything works fine again. Deleted the `looper.prepare()` and my app does not die anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void sendJsonList(final List<String> jsonStrlist,
        final String resturl) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            /* Your HTTP clients code */
            try {
                for (String jsonStr : jsonStrlist) {
                    /* Loop logic */
                    response = client.execute(post);
                    if (response != null) {
                        /*reponse handler logic */
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Looper.loop();
        }
    };

    t.start();
}
```